# How do I state the }while(???) portion of the loop?

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements, do-while

I need this code to loop for however many iterations someone decides to use, I do not understand what condition I would need to put into the {while**(??here??)**;

Also I understand that the loop should go around my input statements and tax computation, have I placed the do and the while in the right position?

EDIT* I've removed 2 of the cases from the code which are pretty much the same so I could post within the rules here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment333 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
      System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
      String name = input.next();

     System.out.println("Enter your age in years:");
      byte age = input.nextByte();

      System.out.println("Enter your gender (F/M):");
      char gender = input.next().charAt(0);

      System.out.println("Enter your marital status (S/M/D/W):");
      char marital_status = input.next().charAt(0);

      System.out.println("Enter your taxable income for 2016:");
      long income = input.nextLong();

      String name_prefix;
      double tax_amount;
      if (gender == 'M') {
        name_prefix = (age < 18) ? "Master." : "Mr.";
      } else {
        name_prefix = (marital_status == 'M') ? "Mrs." : "Ms.";
      }
      switch (marital_status) {
        case 'M':
          if (income < 8500) {
            tax_amount = 0;
            System.out.println(name_prefix + " " + name + ", based on the income provided, you owe no tax for the fiscal year 2016");
          } else {
            if (income < 24000) {
              tax_amount = income * 0.01;
            } else {
              tax_amount = income * 0.025;
            }
            System.out.println(name_prefix + " " + name + ", based on the income provided, you owe a tax of $" + tax_amount + " for the fiscal year 2016");
          }
          break;
        case 'W':
          if (income < 8500) {
            tax_amount = 0;
            System.out.println(name_prefix + " " + name + ", based on the income provided, you owe no tax for the fiscal year 2016");
          } else {
            if (income < 24000) {
              tax_amount = income * .015;
            } else {
              tax_amount = income * 0.034;
            }
            System.out.println(name_prefix + " " + name + ", based on the income provided, you owe a tax of $" + tax_amount + " for the fiscal year 2016");
          }
          while ()
      }
      break;
      default: System.out.println("Sorry! Our system is unable to calculate your tax at this time.");
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you!");
    //closing all objects
    input.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer is why you want to use do while loop?

Comment: @Max You need to format your code and leave just the relevant part here.

Comment: I think you should use `while(true)` and `break` somewhere in the loop, on some condition.

Comment: You say "however many iterations someone decides to use" - how is this decided? Without knowing what condition you want, we cannot help you. Also, please, please format your code. It is impossible to read as it is. (BTW, you probably want a `break` rather than a `while` condition)

Answer (score 0):

You can finish it like this:

```
...
    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (y/n)");

    } while (Objects.equals("y", input.next()))

...
```

Comment: If it's possible for `input.next()` to return `null` the loop will break, usually it's better to put a constant on the left of the `.equals` like `"y".equals(input.next())` because "y" can never be null.

Comment: I just mention it as it seems like Max may be new to programming, figured might as well get him thinking in terms of best practice :)

Comment: One more thing - I think you mean `Objects` not `Object`

Comment: You got it. Corrected.